# How do I procces a node object with Query selector in Javascript using for loops

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nav that I am practicing query selector on. When I run the querie selector objection on the console and add a number inside the bracket node it shows the actual element at the specific index but when I use a for loop to get all the element it said the object is undefined. I am not sure why so any help would be appreciated.Thanks

```
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">WebD<ev</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#html">HTML</a></li>
   <li><a href="#css">CSS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
</ul>
<button class="navbar-toggler">
  <span></span>
</button>
```

```
 var navbarToggler = document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler");
 var navbarMenu = document.querySelector(".navbar ul");
 var navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");

   for(var i = 0 ; i< navbarLinks; i++)
{console.log(navbarLinks[i]);
  }
```

Comment: Please, use: `navbarLinks.length` in: `for(var i = 0 ; i< navbarLinks.length; i++)`.

Comment: You have an issue in the HTML markup in this: `<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">WebD<ev</a>`. Should be: `<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">WebDev</a>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code:

```
var navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");
```

The `navbarLinks` variable contains a [**`NodeList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

So, you can use the `.length` property.

In this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i < navbarLinks.length; i++) {
  console.log(navbarLinks[i]);
}
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var navbarToggler = document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler");
  var navbarMenu = document.querySelector(".navbar ul");
  var navbarLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".navbar a");

  for (var i = 0; i < navbarLinks.length; i++) {
    console.log(navbarLinks[i]);
  }

}());
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">WebDev</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#html">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#css">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#javascript">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button class="navbar-toggler">
  <span></span>
</button>
```